# How to enable save action in Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working under Eclipse plug-in development. I have implemented two view parts to view and change some objects. Each view part implements `ISaveablePart` to save modified objects and enable save button on toolbar.

The problem is: when I select my objects in *Project Explorer*, *Save* button isn't enabled, only *Save All* is enabled.

So I'd like to know is there any ability to enable Save button in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first implement `ISaveablePart`, as you have mentioned above.

You have to fire an event (see `IWorkbenchPartConstants.PROP_DIRTY`), which will in turn ask your editor whether it's dirty (`ISaveablePart#isDirty()`).  If the answer is `true`, then the save button will be enabled.

See `FormEditor#editorDirtyStateChanged()` for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already implemented firing of PROP_DIRTY, but I still have a problem. I have two views which implement ISaveablePart and gets dirty, so when I set focus on them SAVE button is enabled. These views modify properties of the object selected in ProjectExplorer (lets say makes object dirty). So the question: how do I enable SAVE button when focus is set on ProjectExplorer, not these views. I mean how to enable SAVE button when selected object gets dirty and focus is not on there views.

Comment: You're trying to do something that is not naturally supported in the Eclipse framework.  Each part has it's own save life-cycle.  The only way I can see that working is having all your parts register with a global handler of some kind.  There is no way to get around it.  Your ProjectExplorer must implement ISaveablePart, which means you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks for answer! It's true, the only way is to implement my own CommonNavigator, but still there will be a lot of problems.